# No new elements on page using D3

Tags: d3.js

Trying to create simple svg canvas using D3 but looking at elements in the console nothing shows up. D3 seems to be loading because from the console when I type d3. I get the options and methods available in D3. But the svg canvas is not being drawn. What am I missing?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Basic Bar Chart</title>
        <style>     
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="chart"></div>
        <script src="d3.v3.js">

            var w = 500;
            var h = 500;

            function drawSVG(s) {
                var svg = d3.select("#chart")
                    .append("svg")
                    .attr("width",w)
                    .attr("height",h);

                console.log(s);
            }

            var sampleStr = "hello";

            drawSVG(sampleStr);

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've placed your code within the `script` tag that has its source attribute set to download D3:

```
<script src="d3.v3.js">
... your code is here
</script>
```

You need to place your code in its own `script` tag:

```
<script src="d3.v3.js"></script>
<script>
... your code should go here
</script>
```